# Azure Speech-to-text REST API: Create dataset with POST request - Error posting to specific project

Tags: json, python-requests, speech-to-text, azure-speech

I am trying to create a dataset in Azure Speech Studio with the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/rest-speech-to-text#speech-to-text-rest-api-v30). The schema documentation for Create Dataset POST request is [here](https://westeurope.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/speech-to-text-api-v3-0/operations/CreateDataset). I would like to direct the dataset to a specific project, and it should definitely be possible. But when i add the "project" key to my JSON i get an error.

My JSON looks like this:

```
dataset_json = {
  "kind": "AudioFiles",
  "contentUrl": "https://github.com/aguldbrandsen/stuff/blob/main/a3d9b49a-2721-4db4-bc6f-51a005c0cd82_1.zip?raw=true",
  "locale": "da-DK",
  "displayName": "MyName",
  "description": "MyDescription",
  "project": "https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/speechtotext/v3.0/projects/<Project_ID>"
}
```

Without "project" key and value it works fine.

My post with requests:

```
r = requests.post('https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/speechtotext/v3.0/datasets', headers={'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key':KEY}, json=dataset_json)
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The value for project must be { "self" : "https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/speechtotext/v3.0/projects/<Project_ID>" }, not just a string with the location.

For details, you can refer to the schema definition on https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/speech-to-text-api-v3-0/operations/CreateDataset.

Answer (score 1):

The service has a bug at the moment, that only allows content URLs from Azure Blob storage, This has been fixed and will be rolled out next week.